# Python: How to hold cmd session in windows?

Tags: python, windows, session, cmd

I have this problem:
What I am trying to do:
Uninstall program in Windows via cmd.

For that I need to go to cmd, enter wmic, and then call uninstall on specific program and exit.

How do I do that in Python? I mean the commands should be passed in specific order in one session, as the first one runs some program, and the other enters a command for that program. All I have been using so far are just single commands that could be executed by whatever cmd session, and now I'm stuck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you create a batch file and run it from Python instead?

Comment: Or execute the same command lines directly, for that matter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Comment: Well, in batch file when I write "START wmic" - it starts in separate window and it is impossible to interact with it in that batch file. And I need to uninstall the program multiple times and the install it automatically. The installation part is done, I just can't uninstall it now.

Comment: OK so the problem is solved - wmic takes the command also as an agrument, so can be fed directly via cmd in one line.

Comment: However I still don't know how to hold a session in cmd in case I would ever need it...